# How to show x-axis with just month and year in line chart?

Tags: powerbi

I plot a line chart from my data in PowerBI. My data is

| Month | value |
| --- | --- |
| August, 2022 | 89 |
| Septemeber, 2022 | 100 |

Month is of type 'Date' and Value is 'decimal'.  My line chart only has 2 data point, but when Power Bi draws it, is shows in 'days' instead of months  (from my data).
[image]

I have tried creating a 'Hierarchy' for my X-axis. But that does not solve the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the axis type to categorical. For more control, you'll need a date table https://radacad.com/power-bi-date-or-calendar-table-best-method-dax-or-power-query.

[image]